# How can I check whether a variable contains some specific text

Tags: php

how do I check if a variable in php contains text?

eg:

> if ($cn contains 'excel') { ... }

I've currently got the following that works but it is clumsy for if a course name changes then it will not work anymore.

```
if (strpos($cn,'MS Excel 2003/07 (Intro)') !== false) {
...........
}
if (strpos($cn,'MS Excel 2003/07 (Intermediate)') !== false) {
...........
}
if (strpos($cn,'MS Excel 2003/07 (Special)') !== false) {
...........
}
```

Comment: What do you mean if the name change? it can change to what exactly? you could search for "Excel" only.

Comment: Thank you, i tried it earlier but it did not work, don't know what I did then but searching for only excel is working now.  By changing I meant say Intro to Introduction.

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing the course names in a database for easy maintenance.

So something like this would be preferable...

```
// $sources should be an array of course names from the DB

foreach($sources as $name) {
    if( strstr($cn, $name) ) {...}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am storing it in a database.

Answer (score 1):

Each course could have an `ID` as well as a `Name`. Then all of your code could reference courses by ID but you could display the `Name` to the user through the UI.

That way, you can allow the `Name` of a course to change without needing to update your code / add to a list of changes each time.